# Why is my on_member_update running more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that tracks playtime on discord. The first if runs when a game is detected on discord. The second if runs when the game is closed.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):

 if (before.activity is None) and (after.activity is not None):

   uname = after.name
   disc = after.discriminator
   usertag = f"{uname}#{disc}"
   uid = str(after.id)
   gamestarted = str(datetime.utcnow())

   await funcs.storestart(uid, usertag, gamestarted, col)

 if (before.activity is not None) and (after.activity is None):

   uid = str(before.id)
   gname = before.activity.name

   now = str(datetime.utcnow())

   await funcs.addplaytime(uid, gname, now, col)
```

But when I open a game, the on member update event seems to run three times. I put print inside the first if to check if this was the case and turns out it runs three times every time. Anyone know the reasoning for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its running three times because the bot is in 3 guilds. The on member update is firing for each guild the user is in.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to clarify an answer in case anyone comes across this like I did since I had a similar issue (and didn't read the API carefully). Keywords 'before' and 'after' under the function 'on_member_update' are the same as saying 'member'. If you want the bot to run one time and it's in multiple guilds, you can have it look at the change in activity in only one guild. Below is an example:

```
if (before.guild.name == "AGuildNameTheBotIsIn"):
```